# Laravel file upload is null (but it's there in var_dump())

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

This problem at first seemed common upon searching, but most answers have to do with a missing `'files' => true'` in the form open.

So my form has a typical image upload. Everything works fine if I don't first check the input like:

```
    $logo = Input::file('logo');
    $logoName = time() . $logo->getClientOriginalName();
    $logo->move(public_path() . '/logos/', $logoName);
    $user->logo = $logoName;
    $user->save();
```

No problem. The image and filename both upload/save. But when I check first if the logo is there, it skips over because the logo is apparently `null`.

```
if(Input::has('logo')
{
    $logoName = time() . $logo->getClientOriginalName();
    $logo->move(public_path() . '/logos/', $logoName);
    $user->logo = $logoName;
    $user->save();
}
```

Strangely, when I die/dump it shows null despite also showing the logo is there like so:

```
dd(Input::all(), Input::has('logo'));
```

returns a:

```
array (size=4)
  '_token' => string 'pVuQrFqOPNPJgIhU3kUxRuQQqjsqMrBu5LOhLxJH' (length=40)
  'username' => string 'tinak' (length=5)
  'location' => string 'Kuala Lumpur' (length=12)
  'logo' => 
    object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)[9]
      private 'test' => boolean false
      private 'originalName' => string 'logo8.png' (length=9)
      private 'mimeType' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
      private 'size' => int 14315
      private 'error' => int 0
boolean false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `hasFile` to check if a file was uploaded.

```
if (Input::hasFile('logo'))
{
    //
}
```

[Docs - Requests - Files](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files)